# CardView halfway swipe in RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I want to show user menu, under CardView, when he/she swipes it; but I want cardView to stop on half-way during swiping;

I've created MyItemTocuchHelper class and overrided onChildDraw() method:

```
  public class MyItemTocuchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

        .....

        private int mWidth = 128; // this value is calculated, but let's say its 128

...
 @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        if (dX > mWidth) {
            dX = mWidth;
        }

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
    }
@Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return 0.01f;
    }
```

what this does, is that swipe animation stops on certain point (which i wanted to do); but when this view is swiped, swipe distance is set to screen width automaticaly; what I mean is that when I try to swipe it back, onChildDraw() method, is called with dX = 1038.0 at first time and its value decreases as I continue to swipe; so no animation is playing, before dX reaches to mWidth's value. As long as dX;'s value decreases to mWidth's value, animation starts again.

Is there any way, to set for example swipedDX to specific value? or any way around it? What i want is to, start animation as soon as user starts to swipe view back.

thank you in advance